# I need to add a filter to a powershell script that leverages the Miscrosoft Graph SDK module

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, active-directory, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using a Powershell script that uses the Microsoft Graph API SDK to create a CSV and then drop that CSV into "C:\temp". The CSV contains two columns.

Column 1. All of our on-prem AD and Azure AD users Display Names.
Column 2. A timestamp of when they changed their password last.

I would like to filter out any unlicensed user AKA resources, like shared mailboxes and the such.

If possible it would also be nice to be able to add a third column that also flags if they are On-prem or AzureAD. This is not as important as filtering out resources, but would be nice.

My original script to create the 2 column CSV works as expected:

```
Get-MgUser -All | select DisplayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime | Export-Csv "C:\temp\userupdate"
```

I tried adding a filter at the beginning to replace -All:

```
-Filter 'assignedLicenses/$count eq 0'B'
```

But it turns out you cannot use a declared variable for a filter. So then I thought if I was going to start declaring variables I would attempt to both add the third column and filter out resources and used this script:

```
$usersWithLicenses = Get-MgUser -All | Where-Object { $_.AssignedLicenses.Count -gt 0 }

foreach ($user in $usersWithLicenses) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
        LastPasswordChangeDateTime = if ($user.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime) { $user.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime } else { "N/A" }
    }
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\userupdate.csv"
```

This script did not throw any errors but the CSV it created in C:\temp was blank.

Comment: Whats wrong with the `-Filter` approach ? "But it turns out you cannot use a declared variable for a filter..." Unclear what you mean by this but also not true. The filter for getting users having at least 1 license works perfectly fine as long as you use consistencyLevel `eventual`

Comment: What would this look like ? When I try to use it as a filter like this: 

 `Get-MgUser -Filter 'assignedLicenses/$count eq 0' | select DisplayName,lastPasswordChangeDateTime | Export-Csv "C:\temp\userupdate"` 

I am getting this error: Get-MgUser : Expect simple name=value query, but observe property 'assignedLicenses' of complex type 'AssignedLicense'

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you can pipe after a [language keyword, `foreach` in this case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_keywords?view=powershell-7.3#foreach), to fix your code you would need to either capture all output from your loop first and then pipe it to `Export-Csv`:

```bash
# capture output in `$result`
$result = foreach ($user in $usersWithLicenses) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DisplayName                = $user.DisplayName
        LastPasswordChangeDateTime = if ($user.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime) {
            $user.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime
        }
        else {
            'N/A'
        }
    }
}

# pipe here
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\userupdate.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Or, you can change your loop to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.4) (changing `$user` for `$_` to reference the enumerated item), then you can pipe its output directly to `Export-Csv`:

```bash
Get-MgUser -Filter -All |
    Where-Object { $_.AssignedLicenses.Count -gt 0 } |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            DisplayName                = $_.DisplayName
            LastPasswordChangeDateTime = if ($_.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime) {
                $_.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime
            }
            else {
                'N/A'
            }
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\userupdate.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

As aside, you should be able to replace the filter for `$_.AssignedLicenses.Count -gt 0` using the OData filter `assignedLicenses/$count ne 0` as long as you include `-ConsistencyLevel eventual` and `-CountVariable` in your query to enable the [advanced query capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries?tabs=http):

```bash
$getMgUserSplat = @{
    Filter           = 'assignedLicenses/$count ne 0'
    CountVariable    = 'count'
    ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'
    All              = $true
}

$expression = {
    if ($_.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime) {
        return $_.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime
    }

    'N/A'
}

Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat |
    Select-Object DisplayName, @{ N = 'LastPasswordChangeDateTime'; E = $expression } |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\userupdate.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hmmmm. When running the second block, if I remove -Filter it will run. If i leave it in I get a error saying I am missing an argument after -Filter. But the CSV is blank. 

The third block runs without any changes but the CSV is giving me NA for the value of Password update column BUT it is filtering out the resources properly.

Comment: I don't follow the "Same code goes here" I assume the "pipe here" means that's where I would pipe in the code I already have working?

Comment: @MickeyJ edited. also im unsure what you're looking to get with `.PasswordProfile.LastPasswordChangeDateTime`. There is no `LastPasswordChangeDateTime` in [`PasswordProfile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordprofile?view=graph-rest-beta). Maybe you wanted `lastPasswordChangeDateTime` ?

Comment: I didn't realize that about [PasswordProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/passwordprofile?view=graph-rest-beta)

Seens to make more sense as `LastPasswordChangeDateTime =$user.LastPasswordChangeDateTime` but if I run: 

``$result = foreach ($user in $usersWithLicenses) {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
LastPasswordChangeDateTime = $user.LastPasswordChangeDateTime
          }
        }
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\userupdate.csv' -NoTypeInformation``

I get an empty CSV. I am just getting more and more confused at this point.

Comment: Is there a way to check the results are correct before trying to pipe into CSV. I think my error lies in the "#pipe here" as I am not sure what to pipe there. 

I appreciate your helping me.